# Why can I not replace an object in core data when a view loads?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, fetch

For a few days, I've been trying to make this piece of code work. I'm trying to build a simple to do list app using core data, integrating the days left until a certain task. I've put the code in my viewWillAppear function. Normally every time the view appears the daysLeft should be updated, but for some reason my display of daysLeft in my table view remains the same all the time, even after a few days. I've been trying to figure out what might be going wrong, did I put the code in the right function or should it go in viewDidLoad or something like that. Could it be a problem with the simulator and it works on a real iPhone? Maybe I haven't replace the object right, maybe my for loop doesn't work well or it could be something else. I'm completely new to programming as a whole, so this is beyond my understanding. Any help would be much appreciated! Cheers :)

```
var myList: Array<AnyObject> = []

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    let appDeleg: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    let contexts: NSManagedObjectContext = appDeleg.managedObjectContext!
    let freq = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "ToDoList")

    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "itemDaysLeft", ascending: false)
    freq.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]


    myList = contexts.executeFetchRequest(freq, error: nil)!


    for var index = 0; index < myList.count; index++ {

        var data: NSManagedObject = myList[index] as NSManagedObject

        var chosenDate: NSDate = data.valueForKey("userChosenDate") as NSDate
        var todayDate: NSDate = NSDate()

        let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        let components = calendar.components(.DayCalendarUnit, fromDate: todayDate, toDate: chosenDate, options: nil)

        let secondsInADay = ((60 * 60) * 24)
        let newDaysLeft: Int = ((components.hashValue / secondsInADay) + 1)

        var newDaysLeftStr: String = "\(newDaysLeft)"

        myList[index].setValue(NSNumber(short: newDaysLeft), forKey: "itemDaysLeft")
        myList[index].setValue(NSString(UTF8String: newDaysLeftStr), forKey: "daysLeftStr")

// added suggested line by Mike
contexts.save(nil)

    }

    tableView.reloadData()
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let CellID: NSString = "myCell"

    var cell: CustomCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellID) as CustomCell

    if let ip = indexPath as NSIndexPath! {

        var data: NSManagedObject = myList[ip.row] as NSManagedObject
        cell.textLabel?.text = data.valueForKeyPath("itemName") as? String

        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = data.valueForKeyPath("daysLeftStr") as? String

    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: How are you reloading your table? With another fetch request? What does your cellForRowAtIndexPath look like? The problem is likely that you are not saving your changes to your list. To do that, you need to call contexts.save(nil) prior to calling tableView.reloadData(). This persists the changes.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I added the code for my tableView. Saving the contexts makes a lot of sense to me. I didn't think about that, nor did I know I had to save it again. I've added your suggestion to my code. Hopefully it works.

Comment: Your code for calculating days remaining doesn't look right - you should never rely on the `hashValue` of an object having any meaning - it is an opaque value for equality comparison purposes. You don't need to do anything with NSCalendar. Simply call `timeIntervalSinceNow` on `userChosenDate` and divide by 86400

Comment: Since you are loading the table from the same array that you are updating, contexts.save will probably not matter. @Paulw11 makes a good point about your calculation being wrong. I would recommend following his suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. I've tried Paul's suggestion. It doesn't work as of right now. For some reason it keeps on returning 0 when I display the days left in the table view using timeIntervalSinceNow. I'll fool around with it some more maybe it'll work. Hash value has worked for me pretty well so far though.

Comment: Mike, you were right, saving the contexts doesn't solve my problem. It's frustrating since I have to wait a whole 24 hours to see if it works. As of right now, I'm really confused as to why it doesn't work. I'll try to figure something out by myself. If it doesn't work I'll come back to stack overflow for help. Thanks again!